# How to read/convert classic MAC app file on MAC OSX

Tags: macos

I am new to MAC environment.
Is there any way that I can convert classic MAC app file so that it can be read on MAC OS X?
Also, is there any good tutorial for how to write .app file for a JAVA application.
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Support for classic mode ( runs older mac software was dropped with 10.5).  If you search for classic mode you can find some emulators/virtual machines which may run classic apps. I have not tried any of these.

.app is not a file format. It is actually a directory with a defined structure. If you show contents on an app from finder, you can browse this contents of the directory.

As for putting an jar file in an .app bundle, check the help for Jar Bundler. It is included with XCode and can be found under Developer/Applications/Utilites. This utility turns a jar app into a .app bundle.

Comment: I thought they dropped Classic mode with the Intel apps.  My first Intel Mac was running 10.4 but not classic.